# PHP создание строки из значений многомерного массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, к примеру есть массив:

```
$arr = array(
    0=>array(
        'id'=>1,
        'item'=>1
        ),
    1=>array(
        'id'=>2,
        'item'=>4
        ),
    2=>array(
        'id'=>3,
        'item'=>2
    ),
    3=>array(
        'id'=>4,
        'item'=>1
    ),
    4=>array(
        'id'=>5,
        'item'=>5
    )
    );
```

Мне нужно сделать MySql запрос, и получить данные, где `id IN ( перечисление значений ключей item в массивах массива $arr )` , с фильтрацией от повторяющихся значений.

То есть из приведенного в пример массива выше, сделать следующую строку: `$params = '1,4,2,5';`

Не подскажите как сделать это при помощи стандартных функций php, без использования foreach? С ним я примерно понимаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У самого была примерно такая же задача, и кстати аналогично вашему **без использования foreach**, так что думаю, этот код вам подойдет:

```
$data = implode(',', array_unique(array_map(function($arr) {
    return $arr['item'];
}, $arr)));

print_r($data);

Result:
1,4,2,5
```

Comment: `array_column($arr, 'item')`

Comment: @teran да, ваша правка актуальнее.